# Allowing access to USB port in Dockerfile?

Tags: python, docker, raspberry-pi

I've set up BalenaCloud with my Raspberry Pi Zero so that when I push to a repo it automatically downloads on the raspberry pi.
Along with the script I am running I have a `DockerFile` (I don't 100% understand `DockerFiles`).

I have found that my USB device (barcode scanner) connected to the Pi does not work. I know because I can see the logs through BalenaCloud and see that nothing is being displayed when a barcode is scanned.

I'm thinking that it is because I have not included something to do with the USB port in the DockerFile but I am not sure? Here is my `DockerFile`:

```
FROM balenalib/rpi-debian-python:latest

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install python3-pymongo

RUN mkdir -p apps
COPY ./apps/ ./apps/

CMD ["python3", "apps/main.py"]
```

I know my script I am running works with the USB device as when I ran the Pi in desktop mode it worked without an issue.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does it connect? If it's a TCP port you can use the EXPOSE command. If it's a volume (drive) you can't add a port to your dockerfile, you will have to configure a volume at the point you run the container with docker run or docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify device on the docker run command line

```
docker run  (...) --device=/dev/ttyUSB0 (...)
```